# AWS Lambda : Original error was: cannot import name multiarray

Tags: python, numpy, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Hi i deployed an application with lambda aws (using Serverless Framework).
but i receive the error when i run a test

```
START RequestId: 5bcf988a-2064-11e8-8d1e-c5a0129510f Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'handler': 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray
```

I **removed** the numpy package folder multiple times and reinstalled but, still not working
So do you have any solution for this problem ?

for the code :

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'env','Lib','site-packages'))
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import csv
import psycopg2


def hello(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    return "test"
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does your code actually look like?

Comment: @ParrettApps I just added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by changing the environnement.
I didn't know that python is not portable.
I developed the lambda function in my Windows environment, but lambda is usually run in a Linux environment in AWS, and that's why my lambda was not working.
So the solution is to change the environnement, and use Linux instead of windows

Answer (score -1):

I compiled my code on MACOSX environment and was caught in the same problem these days, and even I put my code on ec2 and installed all the dependencies in linux or ubuntu environment, the error is the same.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html docs here gave me the hint that the current lambda execution environment is Public Amazon Linux AMI version (AMI name: amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2),please pay attention to the specific version of AMI, even you use Amazon Linux as your ec2 instance, the newer or older version can make problem.
So after I changed the version of my ec2 instance, recompiled my code on it and store the zipped files on s3, than the AWS lambda run successfully.